# Slide down and stop on page load with CSS only

Tags: html, css, animation

I am trying to get a flash message to slide down from top of page and finish at `top: 100px;`.

My CSS is doing it correctly, but then after the animation runs throught, it reverts back to `top: 0px;` .

I need it to stay at 100px until user closes it, which is done with JS afterwards.
I want the slide to be done just with CSS however.

**here is my CSS:**

```
.flash-messages {
  &__wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    width: 40%;
    left: 30%;
    background: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.85);
    margin: 50px;
    overflow: visible;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeOut;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-name: fadeOut;

    div p {
      color: white;
      font-size: 25px;
      text-align: center;
    }
  }
}


@-webkit-keyframes fadeOut {
    0%      { -webkit-transform: translateY(0%); }
    100% {-webkit-transform: translateY(100px) }
}
```

Here is HTML:

```
<div class="flash-messages__wrapper">
    <div class="flash-messages__close"></div>
    <div n:foreach="$flashes as $flash" n:class="flash, $flash->type">
        <p>{$flash->message}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Use [CSS transisitons](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp) instead they work better then animations when you are moving an element from one state to another.

Answer (score 2):

This may work. I'm using `top` instead of `transform`, and after completing `animation` element returns to it's original state, therefore use `top:100px` in `.flash-messages__wrapper`

```css
.flash-messages__wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  width: 40%;
  left: 30%;
  background: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.85);
  margin: 50px;
  overflow: visible;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeOut;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-name: fadeOut;
  top:100px;
}

.flash-messages__wrapper div p {
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeOut {
  0% {
    top:0;
  }
  100% {
    top:100px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="flash-messages__wrapper">
  <div class="flash-messages__close">

  </div>
  <div n:foreach="$flashes as $flash" n:class="flash, $flash->type">
    <p>{$flash->message}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```